# How to cycle through helm sources?

Tags: helm, cycling, helm-sources

I have multiple sources in helm like this

```
(setq helm-sources '(helm-source-buffers-list
                                  helm-source-recentf
                                  helm-source-dired-recent-dirs
                                  helm-source-emacs-commands-history
                                  helm-source-emacs-commands
                                  helm-chrome-source
                                  hgs/helm-c-source-stars
                                  hgs/helm-c-source-repos
                                  helm-source-buffer-not-found
                                  hgs/helm-c-source-search))
```

I  can goto next source using `C-o`. But when I reach to the last source, `C-o` doesn't go to first source. I  have to kill helm session and start a new one.

How do I make `C-o` to cycle through all sources?

Comment: It seems it doesn't work only when having dummy source, i.e., `helm-source-buffer-not-found`.

Comment: I have made a [PR](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/pull/1117) to try to fix it.

Comment: Fix this problem, but break original function, I will keep working on it.

Comment: The maintainer of helm has fixed this problem with [this commit](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/commit/576cc21f381977e1d3c509d94f73853a74612cff), so your question can be considered resolved.

Comment: Actually Thierry (the current maintainer of helm) fixed this bug, and my fix is wrong and doesn't work good. Now `C-o` can already do what you want, maybe this question can be simply deleted, I think.